# Resizing the nav-tree panel in Doxygen

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, doxygen

I try to personalize the generated html-output of doxygen.

I want to give the readers of the documentation the chance of resizing the nav-tree panel (the left panel), which is not a by default setting of Doxygen, as I observed.

I was thinking that I could activate that feature by adding an custom CSS-file (customdoxygen.css), but I didn't find any solution neither.

Is there a way to make doxygen generate the code, so that the nav-tree panel could be resized by the readers of the documentation?

Comment: By default the panel is resizable and the default width is even configurable via TREEVIEW_WIDTH, so you must be overlooking something. Are you use a customized header that misbehaves perhaps?

Comment: Well, it might be an issue. I gonna check tomorrow and let you know. I'm using a customized header/footer. I've already tried to configure the `TREEVIEW_WIDTH` parameter with no success. The left frame is not resizable, and has a fixed dimension everytime I generate the documentation (no matter which value the `TREEVIEW_WIDTH` has). I can't see the code right now, but I still remember, that the nav-tree was having the parameter `selectable = "off"` in the generated HTML documentation, which is not setted on other doxygen documentations on the internet, where the resizable feature works.

Comment: First try if it works without customized the header, then compare your header with the default one. You may be missing the inclusion of resize.js for instance.

Comment: It might be some problem with the Version of Doxygen that I use (1.7.6.1). I have generated a new documentation without headers. No difference. I also generated a new documentation with the Doxygen-GUI, without headers, only with `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` enabled. Also no difference. I have generated again the default header/footer with `doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen
.css`. The header does not have the `resize.js` script included by default, but the script is included in the html output: `<script src="resize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: I think the Problem should be here somewhere: `<div class="ui-resizable side-nav-resizable" id="side-nav" style="top: 101px; width: 300px; height: 908px;" unselectable="on">` The unselectable parameter is setted on `"on"`. This is the main difference that I observed between the documentations from the Internet with functioning resizable feature and my documentation. It may be some issue by generating the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the Problem in the meanwhile. The issue is caused by an error of Internet Explorer 9:

I have generated the documentation on my personal computer (local). Internet Explorer is setted to not open by default local script files in the browser. The option which refers to that is: `Tools → Internet Options → Advanced → "Allow active content to run on files on My Computer"`.

Now when I open the `index.html` file of the documentation, Internet Explorer blocks the `resize.js` script. Internet Explorer also give you the option to still allow blocked content (the scripts). This is functioning well, with one exception: the `unselectable` parameter of the nav-tree-panel (which is setted by Internet Explorer) will not be disabled/deleted after you allow the blocked content: `<div class="ui-resizable side-nav-resizable" id="side-nav" style="top: 101px; width: 300px; height: 908px;" unselectable="on">`. Therefore the nav-tree panel cannot be resized although the script was loaded.

So the solution could be:

1. Disable this option: `Tools → Internet Options → Advanced → "Allow active content to run on files on My Computer"`
2. Do not use IE9 if you are accessing the generated documentation locally on your computer.